# How do i get all nodes in the graph on a certain relation ship type

Tags: graph, neo4j, iteration, cypher, nodes

I have build a small graph where all the screens are connected and the flow of the screen varies based on the system/user. So the system/user is the relationship type.

I am looking to **fetch all nodes that are linked with a certain relation ship from a starting screen**. I don't care about the depth since i don't know the depth of the graph.
 Something like this, but the below query takes ever to get the result and its returning incorrect connections not matching the attribute {path:'CC'}

**match (n:screen {isStart:true})-[r:NEXT*0..{path:'CC'}]-()
return  r,n**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Make sure you have created an index for `:screen(isStart)`:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON :screen(isStart);
   ```
2. Are you sure you want to include 0-length paths? If not, take out `0..` from your query.
3. You did not specify the directionality of the :NEXT relationships, so the DB has to look at both incoming and outgoing :NEXT relationships. If appropriate, specify the directionality.
4. To minimize the number of result rows, add a `WHERE` clause that ensures that the current path cannot be extended further.

Here is a proposed query that combines the last 3 suggestions (fix it up to suit your needs):

```
MATCH (n:screen {isStart:true})-[r:NEXT* {path:'CC'}]->(x)
WHERE NOT (x)-[:NEXT {path:'CC'}]->()
return r,n;
```